# Microsoft Graph Subscription for start meeting

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm using Microsoft Graph Webhooks to get notifications when an event happens.

My application shows the user his next meeting. On refresh the next meeting is displayed on the screen. To update the next meeting I would like to receive a notification of the start of the next meeting. Is there a way to achieve this with Microsoft Graph Webhooks?

To get the events of the user you would normally make a request like this

```
{
   "changeType": "created,updated",
   "notificationUrl": 
   "https://webhook.azurewebsites.net/api/send/myNotifyClient",
   "resource": "me/events",
   "expirationDateTime":"2016-11-20T18:23:45.9356913Z",
   "clientState": "subscription-identifier"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webhooks are only intended to notify you of changes to the *data* itself. How your application handles that data (i.e. denoting when the start time is) is entirely outside of the API's scope.